# Error 404 - Error displaying views of a Springmvc project

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I am a beginner in spring mvc in general, I am doing a project with that framework in Netbeans, and I am working programmatically instead of working directly with the XML configuration files to configure the servlet. In the index I have a form to search for an element with a specific id, it calls the controller, but the view is not displayed, showing a 404 error that the resource does not exist, but the search I am doing by the get method, and if He performs it. The fact is that I have configured as I see in the spring documentation and on the internet, and even then it does not work. Here I leave the configuration I have, in addition to the packages that are what they contain

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

AppContext class

```
package edu.co.ucatolica.trabajoya.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "edu.co.ucatolica.trabajoya"
})
public class AppContext {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {
            "edu.co.ucatolica.trabajoya.model"
        });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.user"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.pass"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

AppInitializer Class

```
package edu.co.ucatolica.trabajoya.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

/**
 *
 * @author Carlos
 */
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class < ? > [] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {
            AppContext.class
        };
        //return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class < ? > [] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {
            WebMvcConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {
            "/"
        };
    }
}
```

WebMvcConf class

```
package edu.co.ucatolica.trabajoya.config;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

/**
 * @author Ramesh Fadatare
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
    "edu.co.ucatolica.trabajoya.controller"
})
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        source.setBasename("messages");
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        validator.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return validator;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome to Spring Web MVC project</title>
    </head>
    <form action="search" method="get" modelAttribute="trabajos">
        <form:hidden path="id" />
        ID: <input type="text" name="txtIdTrabajo" id="txtIdTrabajo" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar"/>
    </form>

</html>
```

trabajos.jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : trabajos
    Created on : 19/08/2019, 10:48:36 PM
    Author     : Carlos
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

TrabajosController

```
package edu.co.ucatolica.trabajoya.controller;

import edu.co.ucatolica.trabajoya.model.Trabajos;
import edu.co.ucatolica.trabajoya.service.TrabajosService;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

/**
 *
 * @author Carlos
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/trabajos")
public class TrabajosController {
    @Autowired
    private TrabajosService trabajosService;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String list(Model model){
        List<Trabajos> trab = this.trabajosService.list();
        model.addAttribute("trabajos", trab);
        return "list-trabajos";
    }

    @GetMapping("/search")
    public String search(@RequestParam("txtIdTrabajo")int id, Model model){
        Trabajos t = this.trabajosService.search(id);
        model.addAttribute("trabajo", t);
        return "trabajos";
    }
}
```

The packages that I have are the following:

edu.co.ucatolica.trabajoya.model = Project entities are saved

edu.co.ucatolica.trabajoya.dao = Project DAO classes

edu.co.ucatolica.trabajoya.services = Project service classes are saved

edu.co.ucatolica.trabajoya.config = All the application settings are saved, here are the 3 main classes of project configuration

edu.co.ucatolica.trabajoya.controller = Package all project controllers

Project

[image project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoXFv.png)

I can not put the image of the project as such, since I do not yet have range for it

I want to know I can only see the views without any problem and solve that error 404. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `index.jsp` file at the same level as your `WEB-INF` folder.

Comment: The problem is not with `index.jsp`, since this is displayed, the problem is with the other views. Even so, I moved them at all levels and cannot access the index or the other views inside the `jsp` folder